# Git update hook to reject non-ascii file names

Tags: git, shell

I've tried writing a git `update` hook that prevents pushing commits that add files with non-ascii filenames similar to the `pre-commit` hook distributed with git.

The problem is that the server already does some rewriting on the file names before the hook runs. I use `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $rev` to get the files in the rev that is being updated but a file that was commited with a non-ascii character shows up as one with escaped codes.

How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repo has to be configured with `core.quotepath = false`. Then the right file-names show up and my hook works as expected.

Comment: With `core.quotepath = true` you could maybe look for the backslahes. Any filename requiring escaping is a potential problem.